# Basic python, def function and recall for a text-menu

Tags: python, menu, function

I've just started playing around with python and was looking for advice.

The problem is with the MENU(), for some reason on the 7th line I get a syntax error

```
    $ MENU()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
def MENU():
    print("Menu:")
    print("     0. Menu")
    print("     1. Random Number Generator")
    access = int(input("Make a selection from the above list: ")

MENU()   ## Problem area

if access == 1:
    ## Random Number Generator
    import random
    ## Imports random functions
    count = 0
    b = 0
    ## Creates the loop function, printing out the dataset
    while count < 100:
        count += 1
        a = random.randrange(1,101)
        print(count,". ", a, end=" | " )
        b += a
    ## Shows the average values for the program, output
    else:
        print()
        print("Finish!")
        print(b)
        print(b/100)
        menu()
else:
    MENU()
```

Context: I'm using this system just to improve my language as well as prevent myself creating 100's of 10 line files.

Comment: For some reason the program part didn't format properly, I'm sure I did it correctly, however it doesn't affect the visibility of where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 4):

You missed the closing brackets in line 5:

```
access = int(input("Make a selection from the above list: "))
                                                            ^
```

Answer (score 3):

I have just had browse through your code, and while you probably have it figured out now I thought a few suggestions might help you get more into python.

Firstly, style is really important with python, being a white space language. The language also has some great features that can condense the amount of code down, which again encourages a good style. There is something called PEP guides, which introduce this. [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the style guide for python, I would highly recommend reading through it, if you are getting more into python.

Also when I was learning python I found this [learning python the hard way guide](http://sheddingbikes.com/LearnPythonTheHardWay.pdf) an excellent resource. Python is really fun when you get into, hope you're enjoying it! Below is another version of your code that might make more sense.

```
import random # All imports should be at the top, if you know 
              # you are going to use them.

def menu():
    print("Menu:")
    print("     0. Menu")
    print("     1. Random Number Generator")
    access = int(input("Make a selection from the above list: "))
    return access # See explanation

access = menu() # See explanation

if access == 1:
    count = 0
    b = 0

    while count < 100:
        count += 1
        a = random.randrange(1,101)
        print(count,". ", a, end = " | " )
        b += a

    print()
    print("Finish!")
    print(b)
    print(b/100)
    menu()

else:
    menu()
```

**Explanation: It is important to store the value of access into a variable here. You cannot set a value inside a function and expect it to update for the rest of the script. This is because of scoping.

**Also if you are expecting the menu to be called again every time after a selection has been executed you while need to rethink the structure somewhat.

Another way of doing this is to use a for loop. To do this you would having something like:

```
    for i in range(100):
         a = random.randrange(1,101)
         print(count,". ", a, end = " | " )
         b += a

    print()
    print("Finish!")
    print(b)
    print(b/100)
    menu()
```

Comment: If you're trying to show him python style, you should do `if access:` instead of `if access == 1` and `for count in range(100):` instead of `count = 0`, `while count < 100`, and `count += 1`. Undo your change to his print statement: he's using Python 3, `end` makes perfect sense. Also, get rid of the `else` on the `while` or `for` loop: it should only be used if sometimes you `break` out of the loop, otherwise it's the same as putting the statements after the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have spent most of my career in and around vfx where python 3.0 is rarely used yet.

I purposely tried not to edit his code to much, hoping it would be more beneficial to him learning wise to fix it himself after reading through the guide. 

When I am trying to learn something I find it hard when people make all of the corrections for me.

Comment: No criticism intended, I just thought I'd mention the other changes (especially 'end') since you were already talking about style, and they didn't deserve a new answer.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound offended. I just answered it briefly and perhaps didn't consider the answer as a whole as well as I might have, so thanks for pointing that out. I apologize if it came across that way.